# HTML: Adding commas and limited decimal places of a number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I've figured out in the past that if I want a number `100000` to have commas then I just add .toLocaleString() to the angularJS variable. ie:

```
<span>{{variable.toLocaleString()}}</span>
```

Also, if want to limit the number of decimal places to a number `20.34343434` to lets say 2, then I would just add .toFixed(2). ie:

```
<span>{{variable.toFixed(2)}}</span>
```

Now I would like to do both. ie:

```
<span>{{variable.toFixed(2).toLocaleString()}}</span>
```

or

```
<span>{{variable.toLocaleString().toFixed(2)}}</span>
```

but neither seem to work. Maybe the solution to this has nothing to do with either function.

**Question**: How do I add commas and limit the amount of decimal places in a value using HTML and angularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [`currency` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) using an empty string for the currency symbol:

```
{{variable | currency:""}}
```

If you want to change the number of decimal places, you can specify it as an argument (default is 2):

```
{{variable | currency:"":3}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using function then you can use:

```
{{variable.toLocaleString("nu", {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2})}}
```

This will take care of both commas/spaces (depending on locale) in integer digits as well as separator (. or ,) depending on locale.